# How to return number of unique user per publisher in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, distinct

We need RESTful call to ES which will return to us number of unique users per publisher for the given search terms.

The question would be: Return the list of all unique users which have queried the system with any of these search terms:

- rent a car
- car rental
- rent an auto

In MySQL the query would look something like this:

```
SELECT userId, publisherId FROM keywordPixel WHERE (keywordId LIKE '/^(?=.*\brent\b)(?=.*\ba\b)(?=.*\bcar\b).*$/' OR keywordId LIKE '/^(?=.*\bcar\b)(?=.*\brental\b).*$/' OR keywordId LIKE '/^(?=.*\brent\b)(?=.*\ban\b)(?=.*\bauto\b).*$/' ) AND date >= [start] AND date <= [end]
```

This query searches for users who have in their search query at least one line which match the words inside search term. Example, if the user A searched for "Berlin car to rental" this will match the search term "car rental" and this user should be in our result

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(userId)), publisherId FROM keywordPixel WHERE (keywordId LIKE '/^(?=.*\brent\b)(?=.*\ba\b)(?=.*\bcar\b).*$/' OR keywordId LIKE '/^(?=.*\bcar\b)(?=.*\brental\b).*$/' OR keywordId LIKE '/^(?=.*\brent\b)(?=.*\ban\b)(?=.*\bauto\b).*$/') AND date >= [start] AND date <= [end]  GROUP BY publisherId
```

Second query should be the COUNT of distinct users per publihser for the same query.

My solution is something like this:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/keyword*/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            { "match_phrase": { "keywordId.keywordId_analyzed": "Honda " } },
            { "match_phrase": { "keywordId.keywordId_analyzed": "car rental" } },
            { "match_phrase": { "keywordId.keywordId_analyzed": "rent an auto" } }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "from": "2015-04-01T12:20:15+00:00",
            "to": "2015-04-25T12:20:15+00:00"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
 "aggs": {
    "unique_users" : {
      "terms" : { "field" : "publisherId" }
    }
  },
  "_source": ["userId", "publisherId", "keywordId"]
}'
```

but it doesn't return unique users per publisher. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 2):

[Cardinality aggregation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) is what you are looking for

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/keyword*/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            { "match_phrase": { "keywordId.keywordId_analyzed": "Honda " } },
            { "match_phrase": { "keywordId.keywordId_analyzed": "car rental" } },
            { "match_phrase": { "keywordId.keywordId_analyzed": "rent an auto" } }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "from": "2015-04-01T12:20:15+00:00",
            "to": "2015-04-25T12:20:15+00:00"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
 "aggs": {
    "unique_users" : {
      "cardinality" : { "field" : "publisherId" }
    }
  },
  "_source": ["userId", "publisherId", "keywordId"]
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Cardinality is certainly what I'm looking for, but not like that, because it will return me number of unique publishers, and I don't want that, I want number of unique users per publishers, so this is solution:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/keyword*/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            { "match_phrase": { "keywordId.keywordId_analyzed": "rent a car" } },
            { "match_phrase": { "keywordId.keywordId_analyzed": "car rental" } },
            { "match_phrase": { "keywordId.keywordId_analyzed": "rent an auto" } }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "from": "2015-04-01T12:20:15+00:00",
            "to": "2015-04-25T12:20:15+00:00"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "users_per_publisher": {
      "terms": { "field" : "publisherId" },
      "aggs": {
        "number_of_unique_users": {
          "cardinality": {"field" : "userId"}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "_source": ["userId", "publisherId", "keywordId"]
}'
```